# How do install libraries for both Lua5.2 and 5.1 using Luarocks?

Tags: lua, luajit, luarocks

I am writing a small Lua project and using Luarocks to install my 3rd-party dependencies. The default Lua version on my machine is 5.2 and up to this point everything is working just fine.

However, today I have stumbled across a problem that is confusing me. I want to run my program on Lua 5.1 and Luajit to see if it would also work on those versions but I am having a hard time getting Luarocks to download the appropriate versions of the dependencies. As a last resort hack, I have tried to tell Lua5.1 to use the 5.2 libraries that Luarocks installed (by setting the `LUA_PATH` environment variable to the same value as `LUA_PATH_5_2`) but unfortunately that is not enough: my project depends on LuaFileSystem, a C-based module, so I'm going to need to have separate versions of it installed for 5.1 and 5.2.

What do I have to do to install both the 5.1 and 5.2 versions of my dependencies? Do I need to pass some parameters to the`luarocks install` command? Do I need to have multiple instances of Luarocks installed on my machine? One thing that confuses me is that the inside the `.luarocks` folder things are classified under a 5.2 subfolder (~/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/), suggesting that maybe there could be a way to install things in a sibling `5.1` folder but at the same time there is only one `bin` folder, suggesting that luarocks is only able to handle one version of Lua at a time...

Comment: Note: for the benefit of those who posted an answer, it would be nice if you could clarify what operating system you're talking about. Because you mention a `~/.luarocks` folder, it's highly likely that you're using a Un*x variant — possibly macOS _or_ Linux — but instructions for either are not 100% identical. Also, if you could clarify what package manager you use (dpkg, rpm, apt, Hmebrew, snap, others...), or, alternatively, state that you prefer to compile everything locally.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Based on your reference to `~/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/`, you seem to be running a Unix system (Linux or Mac). You can install the latest version of LuaRocks twice, for both Lua 5.1 and Lua 5.2 like this:

```sh
./configure --lua-version=5.1 --versioned-rocks-dir
make build
sudo make install
```

And then again for 5.2:

```sh
./configure --lua-version=5.2 --versioned-rocks-dir
make build
sudo make install
```

This will get you `/usr/local/bin/luarocks-5.1` and `/usr/local/bin/luarocks-5.2`. If you installed Lua 5.1 and 5.2 in /usr/local/, and each of them will use its own `~/.luarocks/lib/luarocks/rocks-5.x/` entry for the user tree (and `/usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks-5.x` for the system tree), and install modules to the right location at `/usr/share/lua/5.x/` and  `~/.luarocks/share/lua/5.x/` (and likewise for `lib`) appropriately.

Comment: When I ran `configure for` 5.1 I got the following error: `Lua version detected: 5.2 This clashes with the value of --with-lua-version.`. I managed to workaround it by by passing an additional `--lua-suffix=5.1` parameter. However, is this something that everyone else is going to have to do or was it just me?

Comment: That happened because your "lua" binary was detected first. Your workaround is fine. I just committed a change to make it unnecessary in future releases: https://github.com/keplerproject/luarocks/commit/b45af8b9e4eac479bd1258720a20424e637ef06a

Answer (score 8):

As suggested by moteus, I decided to install a second version of Luarocks for Lua 5.1. But he is using Windows and I am using Linux so here is what I did:

- Download the source for the latest version of Luarocks on the [Luarocks website](http://luarocks.org/en/Download)
- From the source directory, run the `./configure` script:

  `/configure --prefix="${HOME}/.luarocks51" --lua-suffix=5.1`

  The prefix setting tells Luarocks to put its stuff on the `.luarocks51` folder, next to the existing `.luarocks` folder from my 5.2 install of Luarocks. The lua-suffix parameter tells Luarocks to use Lua 5.1 instead of the default lua version in my machine (5.2). This depends on me having named the interpreter for Lua 5.1 as `lua5.1` (Debian installed mine on `/usr/bin/lua5.1`). Finally, Luarocks managed to automatically detect where the 5.1 headers and libraries are installed (`/usr/include/lua5.1/`) but if it didn't I guess I could have specified that with the `--with-lua-include` and `--with-lua-lib` parameters.
- Compile Luarocks with `make`
- Install it with `make isntall` (no need for Sudo since I'm installing it in a local directory).
- [Configure my 5.1 environment](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-package.path) to use the libraries downloaded by Luarocks. I added the following to my .bashrc:

  ```
  export PATH=$PATH:~/.luarocks/bin:~/.luarocks51/bin
  export LUA_CPATH=";;${HOME}/.luarocks51/lib/lua/5.1/?.so"
  export LUA_PATH=";;${HOME}/.luarocks51/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;${HOME}/.luarocks51/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua"

  export LUA_CPATH_5_2=";;${HOME}/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.2/?.so"
  export LUA_PATH_5_2=";;${HOME}/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/?.lua;${HOME}/.luarocks/share/lua/5.2/?/init.lua"
  ```

  The 5.1 configuration also works for Luajit.
- The executable for the 5.1 version of luarocks is named `luarocks-5.1`:

  ```
  luarocks-5.1 install lfs
  ```

Answer (score 5):

You have to mention both lua version and lua dir in the latest versions:

```
luarocks --lua-dir=$(brew --prefix)/opt/lua@5.1 --lua-version=5.1 install lua-cassandra
```

Comment: You should just add a small note on your answer saying that this applies to environments using Homebrew as a package manager (mostly macOS, but these days also Linux); the OP is not clear about _what_ OS he uses...

Answer (score 2):

Using homebrew, you can do:

```
brew install lua51  # Lua 5.1
brew install lua    # Lua latest
```

Luarocks comes with Lua, so you can do:

```
# Install Lua 5.1 version of any package
luarocks-5.1 install moonscript

# Install Lua latest version of any package
luarocks install moonscript
```

Comment: Note: `lua51` is a deprecated package; the correct one is `lua@5.1`. `luarocks` should, these days, easily figure out which version of Lua to use, but using @Kamyar's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57908883/1035977) it's more certain that it'll find the 'right' version of Lua...