# Lua cannot find installed luarocks on Ubuntu

Tags: lua, luarocks, cjson

I install luarocks:

```
$ sudo apt-get install luarocks
```

I install lua-cjson by luarocks:

```
$sudo luarocks install lua-cjson
```

show packages:

```
$luarocks list

Installed rocks:
----------------
lua-cjson
   2.1.0-1 (installed) - /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks
```

So, I see package:

```
$luarocks show lua-cjson

License:    MIT
Homepage:   http://www.kyne.com.au/~mark/software/lua-cjson.php
Installed in:   /usr/local
. . . 
Modules:
    cjson
    lua2json
    json2lua
    cjson.util


    lua-cjson
          2.1.0-1 (installed) - /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks
```

But, Lua can't see the module:

```
$lua
Lua 5.2.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2013 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> require "cjson"
stdin:1: module 'cjson' not found:
....


$locate cjson.so
 /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/cjson.so
```

What it is the error??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem seems to be that `luarocks` by default installs things for Lua 5.1 (this is the behavior if you installed it using `apt-get`). If you don't mind using Lua 5.1, you can just use that instead (by typing `lua5.1`), and `require "cjson"` should work fine.

If you really want `cjson` for Lua 5.2, it's a bit more complicated. First, you need to make sure that you have the development files for Lua 5.2. Try

```
sudo apt-get install liblua5.2-dev
```

Then download the latest version of the source for `luarocks` [here](http://keplerproject.github.io/luarocks/releases/). Extract, and `cd` to the directory in a terminal.

Then do the following commands (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321560/how-do-install-libraries-for-both-lua5-2-and-5-1-using-luarocks))

```
./configure --lua-version=5.2 --versioned-rocks-dir
make build
sudo make install
```

This will install a version of `luarocks` which works with Lua 5.2. You can then install `cjson` using

```
sudo luarocks-5.2 install lua-cjson
```

You should then be able to use `cjson` in Lua 5.2.

Comment: Thanks for this solution! This really helps with the installation of the correct luarocks version, as the default in Ubuntu 18.04 is still outdated and uses Lua 5.1